# JQuery form string length validation

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have some JQuery form validation where im checking the length of the username is not long for the database but it seems to be returning true eveytime.

Am I missing something?

**HTML**

```
<form name="contact" method"post" action="">
<fieldset>

<label for="username" id="username_label" class="form_label">Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />
<label class="error" for="username" id="username_error">This field is required.        </label>
<label class="error" for="username" id="username_length">Your Username should be less than 30 characters.</label>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
$('.error').hide();
$(".button").click(function() {
  // validate and process form here

$('.error').hide();
  var username_length = $("input#username").val().length;
    if (username_length < 30) {
    $("label#username_length").show();
    $("input#username").focus();
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the `HTML` code too? Cannot judge anything just looking at the JavaScript.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you have posted, you will need to show the form too, as it seems the problem is elsewhere

Comment: I should clarify the code is executed on click of a button all the other validation works except this so i don't believe its the on click or the html

Comment: There is now need to add element type for id selector `id` is unique, anything that add to it, will **increase the overhead** of the selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have some JQuery form validation where im checking the length of the username is not long for the database but it seems to be returning true eveytime.

You are checking if unsername is shorter then 30, not longer!

```
if (username_length < 30) {// !!!
```

note:

- There is no need to add element type for id selector id is unique, anything added to it, will increase the overhead of the selector

`$("input#username")` => `$('#username')`

Comment: @HeDares. embarrassing... Don't worry, things like that happens to everyone.

Answer (score 7):

You can use JQuery Validator plugin to do this;

just need change your html for something like this;

```
<label for="username">User Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"  value="..." />
```

using this approach you don't need define this multiple tags labels with differents ids (username_error, username_length) to handle every single constraint message,and don't need worry about hide these tags, the jquery plugin will handle this for you and put the appropriate message in lable rotule with 'username' for you. And fell free to customize this messages.

your js will be like these;

```
$("form[name=contact]").validate({
//...
rules: {
        username: {
            required: true,
            maxlength: 30
}
//...
});
```

your code will be more clean, See API documetation for more information, http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation